# How do these mass airdrops send tokens?

Tags: gas, airdrop, scam

So there are a couple scams where they send tokens to millions of addresses and when they attempt to approve them the approve function mints Chi Gas Token and sends them back to the scammer. The contract, of course, it's not published.

What I'm curious about is, how do they send them to so many accounts for so cheap? Here, they paid BNB 0.009 for 4000 addresses, about BNB 0.0000024 each, while executting transfer or mint functions normally costs about 0.0003, 125 times more expensive:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xfb3e7dc906d754337cdc5bc3b8ee0ace0ef7263e858c6c63ffec41aa557f613b#eventlog

Here's the decompilation, although I couldn't find the transfer or mint functions:

https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x000000000cd2b9dccf0d5672cd577c982856b6a6

Comment: They are likely just generating log events and not modifying EVM state.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a batch transaction. The smart contract is using a "special" version of `transfer` function to allocate tokens to owners.

In the `transfer` function:

```
Function: transfer(uint256 orderId, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp, bytes sign)
```

the `bytes sign` parameter is an array containing all addresses that will receive the "airdrop", and the function itself just create new entries for these addresses and allocate tokens to them. The token amount is the second parameter.

It is a single transaction that updates multiple balances in one call, therefore it is much cheaper to call.

From decompiler:

```
  def unknown1d59ec2a(): # not payable
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 128
  require cd <= 18446744073709551615
  require cd <ΓÇ▓ calldata.size
  require ('cd', 100).length <= 18446744073709551615
  require cd('cd', 100).length + 36 <= calldata.size
  idx = 0
  s = 0
  while idx < cd:
      mem[0] = cd[36]
      log Transfer(
            address from=cd
            address to=stor16,
            uint256 tokens=cd[((20 * idx) + 152)])
      idx = idx + 1
      s = cd[((20 * idx) + 152)]
      continue 
  if cd[68]:
      if caller == stor3:
          require ext_code.size(0x4946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c)
          call 0x0000000000004946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c.free(uint256 wad) with:
               gas gas_remaining wei
              args cd[68]
          if not ext_call.success:
              revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
          require return_data.size >=ΓÇ▓ 32
      else:
          if caller == stor17:
              require ext_code.size(0x4946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c)
              call 0x0000000000004946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c.free(uint256 wad) with:
                   gas gas_remaining wei
                  args cd[68]
              if not ext_call.success:
                  revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
              require return_data.size >=ΓÇ▓ 32
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of someting like that in the mean time. I did a function which takes an array and just updates the balances. Since they just mint a fixed amount, I omitted that param. It works, it seems, and the cost for each address doesn't vary too much, wheter 10 or 100.


`function crappyMint(address[] memory addresses) public virtual {
         for(uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
             _balances[addresses[i]] += 100000;
         }                 
  }`

Is it necessary to use a for loop, though? There's probably a better way.

Comment: If I did the math correctly, it costs like 80000 wei for 26 address, or 0.000003307 ETH each. It's more expensive than that tx, but close.